# CUDA vs FPGA for Image Processing; which is better

Tags: image-processing

Is there anyone with Image Processing background who can suggests which one is better for Image Processing algorithms among [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and [FPGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fpga). I'm specifically looking to write code for Wavelet Transform and Discrete Cosine Transform and eventually writing code for Quantization and Arithmatic coding, but i am confused which hardware programming language should i focus on among CUDA and FPGA.

Here are few questions i want to ask,

- Which one is better for Image Processing like compression, watermarking etc ?
- Which one is Faster ?
- Which one is easy to    implement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you have a chance to look at [Spiral](http://spiral.net/hardware/ldpc.html) site?  They try to address this question.  For example, there are special cases where FPGA will run O(N) instead of the customary O(N log N).

Here's a [paper](http://spiral.ece.cmu.edu:8080/pub-spiral/pubfile/paper_52.pdf) that deals with generating FPGA.

All the way at the end of [benchmarks page](http://spiral.net/bench.html) they show performance of a software algorithm enhanced with FPGA-based solvers.

P.S.  It's worth noting that Spiral can be used to optimize algorithms other than FFT, but presented data outlines the popular case only.

Answer (score 4):

The question you've asked is not that easy to answer. It depends on many factors.

I will try to give you explanations in the opposite order:

> Which one is easy to implement ?

There is no direct comparison between CUDA and FPGA as CUDA is a programming language and FPGA is hardware architecture. FPGAs can be programmed either in HDL (Verilog or VHDL) or on higher level using OpenCL. CUDA on the other hand is a programming language specially designed for Nvidia GPUs.

So, you can compare:

- FPGA to GPU or
- CUDA to OpenCL or HDL

Programming a GPU in CUDA is definitely the easiest way. If you don't have any experience with HDL it will almost surely be too much of a challenge for you. 
OpenCL for FPGA could be a way to go. However, it is harder to implement and probably a lot more expensive.

> Which one is Faster ?

GPU runs faster, but FPGA can be more efficient.

GPU has the potential of running at a speed higher than FPGA can ever reach. But only for algorithms that are specially suited for that. If the algorithm is not optimal, the GPU will loose a lot of performance.

FPGA on the other hand runs much slower, but you can implement problem-specific hardware that will be very efficient and get stuff done faster.

It's kinda like eating your soup with a fork very fast vs. eating it with a spoon more slowly.

> Which one is better for Image Processing like compression, watermarking etc ?

GPU was invented for pixel-wise image processing, so you can expect it to perform better. Compression is mostly signal processing, so I would place my bet on the FPGA. Watermarking will be faster on GPU.

Both devices base their performance on parallelization, but each in a slightly different way. If the algorithm can be granulated into a lot of pieces that execute the same operations (keyword: SIMD), the GPU will  be faster. If the algorithm can be implemented as a long pipeline, the FPGA will be faster. 
Also, if you want to use floating point, FPGA will not be very happy with it :)

There are some examples for FPGA algorithms on [Altera site](https://www.altera.com/products/design-software/embedded-software-developers/opencl/developer-zone.html#design-examples). Most of those can beat GPU solutions.

There are tons of examples and libraries for CUDA.

Sources: I wrote a master's thesis on comparing performance of FPGAs (OpenCL) and GPUs 
[Algorithm Acceleration on FPGA with OpenCL](https://tumde-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/jure_zdovc_tum_de/EQJ7I01Sbs5Hn1SeDm4Fd9IBmZ5zxSB5UedGFucxVspl-g?e=XSGjkE)

Comment: Can you please add a link to the thesis or other suitable references if available?

Comment: It's not published anywhere online, so I can only give you my onedrive link. I don't know if there is any convention on hating such links---
[Algorithm Acceleration on FPGA with OpenCL](https://tumde-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/jure_zdovc_tum_de/EQJ7I01Sbs5Hn1SeDm4Fd9IBmZ5zxSB5UedGFucxVspl-g?e=XSGjkE)

Comment: Thank you. No particular "hate" as far as I am aware (?). I am not asking for me specifically but since the last phrase of your answer refers to the thesis, I thought it would be good to include a link to it. You can edit your answer to add the link to the main body. All the best.

Comment: I included the link in the answer. Could you please upvote my answer if you found it useful. I'm in a desperate need for reputation so I can use stackexchange normally.

Comment: I thought FPGA is way faster then GPU. Creating a switch to turn the lights on in FPGA is same as connecting the light directly to the battery with a wire, so technically FPGA should be way faster then any cpu based compute platform.